# How to check JSON object and array

Tags: android, json

I have 2 links; which gives json data. I am trying to get the values from the urls from the same activity in android using asynTask. did the coding till converting the data to string(stored it in **jsonStr1**). But now comes the problem. Because,among the 2 urls: 
one starts with JSON object-

```
{    "contacts": [     {"id": "c200", "name": "Ravi Tamada"  },

                       { "id": "c201", "name": "Johnny Depp" }
                ]
 }
```

another start with JSON array-

```
 [{"appeId":"1","survId":"1"}, 
   {"appeId":"2","survId":"32"}
  ]
```

Now how am i going to give a condition for them whether to know its a JSON array or Object? JSON array are object that i know but cant find how to separate them. i have tried the below:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr1);
   if(jsonObj instanceof JSONArray){}
```

but if condition is showing error- *incompatible  conditional operand types JSONObject and JSONArray*

Comment: You have to write two different JSON parser for each URL. You will already what are you expecting either Object or Array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use [startsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) for String to check where the String starts with `{` or `[`

```
boolean isJsonArray = jsonResponse.startsWith("[");
if(isJsonArray){
   // Its a json array
}
else{
   // Its a json object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSONTokener class for that, here is a sample code for that.

```
Object json = new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
if (json instanceof JSONObject){
  JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response);
}
else if (json instanceof JSONArray){
    JSONArray resultArray = new JSONArray(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make jsonobject and call which place u want to calling

```
                    jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://ampndesigntest.com/androidapi/CURRENTPROJECTDATA/textfiles/hotels");

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put("rank", jsonobject.getString("rank"));
                map.put("country", jsonobject.getString("country"));
                map.put("population", jsonobject.getString("population"));
                map.put("flag", jsonobject.getString("flag"));
            //    map.put("latlongitude", jsonobject.getString("latlongitude"));


                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method `has(String)` to check if the `JSONObject` contains or not the key contacts.

```
if(jsonOjbect.has("contacts") {
   ...
}
else {
   ...
}
```